# Link a javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I made a javascript and I need to link it into the aspx-file.
I tried to link it right inside the head content.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="Server">
    <script src="/Fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
    <script src="/Fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.flat.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/urlauslesen.js"></script>
```

But it doesn't work like this,so I tried it inside the div and it worked.

```
<div id="zwei" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; height: 100%; width: 100%; z-index:-1">
    <script>
    var url = window.location.href;
    var params = url.split('?');
    var id = params[1].split('=')[1]; //params[1] will contain everything after ? 
    console.log(id);
    if (id == 11) {
        $("#zwei").each(function() {
            $(this).css("z-index", 0);
        });

    } else if (id == 31) {
        $("#vier").each(function() {
            $(this).css("z-index", 0);
        });
    }
    </script>
    <asp:Literal ID="ltrRenderChart2" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```

But only the if is working, the else if doesn't work.
Why not?

Thanks

Comment: Is 31 being logged in your console when it should be?

Comment: From head content, `$("#zwei")` or `$("#vier")` doesn't match any element, because none are available at this time. Wrap code in document ready pseudo event or load script just before `</body>` closing tag

Comment: `.each` on an ID selector... ID's **must** be unique!

Comment: @tymeJV So can I just write .function?